# how to count row of isolated storage setting?

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I stored multiple data in isolated storage setting but when retrive data at that time only one data is displayed

I use for loop  but its not giving perfect out put

c# code is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Count; i++)
    {
      cityname = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["CityDetail"] as string;
      ads.Add(new Transaction(cityname));
    }
```

saving code for isolated storage setting

```
 if (!setting.Contains("CityDetail"))
 {
   setting.Add("CityDetail", cityname);
 }
 else
 {
   setting["CityDetail"] = cityname; 
 }
 setting.Save();
```

Comment: How are you saving the data to Isolated Storage ??

Comment: @ Amresh Kumar:please see my edited code

Answer (score 1):

The [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) uses *Key-Value* pair to save data.
So for example if you do:

```
 if (!setting.Contains("CityDetail"))
 {
   setting.Add("CityDetail", "abc");
 }
 else
 {
   setting["CityDetail"] = "abc"; 
 }
 setting.Save();
```

So after doing this, the **value** for the **key - CityDetail** is **abc**.

After this if you do:

```
 if (!setting.Contains("CityDetail"))
 {
   setting.Add("CityDetail", "def");
 }
 else
 {
   setting["CityDetail"] = "def"; 
 }
 setting.Save();
```

Then, the **value** for the key **CityDetail** will be replaced and the new **value** will be **def**.
The essence is **"In Key-Value storage method, there can be only one value for one key."**

To save multiple values against a single key, you can do something like this:

```
void addCityName(string cityName)
{
    List<string> existingList = getCityNames();
        if(existingList==null)
        {
             existingList = new List<string>();
             existingList.Add(cityName);
        }
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exitingList);
        if(!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("CityDetails"))
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("CityDetails",json);    
    }
    else 
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["CityDetails"] = json;
    }
}

List<string> getCityNames()
{
    string json = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["CityDetails"] as string;
    if(json == null)
        return null;
    JArray arr = JArray.parse(json);
        List<string> list = new List();
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        list.add(arr[i].toString());
    }
    return list;
}
```

For this you need the [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/92198) library.

Comment: :yes that is the problem and my cityname is came dynemically so how i solve this problem?